# How do I change GHC's compile directory?

Tags: haskell, compilation, ghc

I have a program, say `src/sample.hs`, and I want it to compile (using `ghc --make`) to `build/sample.exe`.

I've figured out how to map the `.hi` and `.o` files over to the build folder, but I can't seem to find anything on how to compile the executable to a different directory. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about explicitly setting the output filename including the directory? Works over here, I haven't tested on Windows so I'm not sure if you need the .exe extension or not.

```
ghc --make -o build/sample.exe src/sample.hs
```

Also worth noting: `--make` is enabled by default as of GHC 7.0.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm not sure why, but I couldn't find that anywhere...this works nicely.